# How to escape validation of a parent class field in child class in hibernate validator

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

Suppose I have one parent class:

```
Class Employee {

@NotNull
private String empName;

//setter and getter

}
```

and a child class that extends the parent:

```
Class ContractEmployee extends Employee  {

}
```

My requirement is that if I pass Employee  object to hibernate validator then Not null validation should happen on empName field which is happening if I do so. But, if I pass ContractEmployee  object to hibernate validator then Not null validation should not happen. How can I escape/bypass this not null validation for ContractEmployee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend against such a design as it violates the Liskov substituation principle. A client of the `Employee` contract relies on the fact that `empName` is not null. This invariant should not be violated by sub-types of `Employee`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion @ Gunnar